# Ignore base class members when serializing

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

How do we ignore a particular base class member when serializing an object of derived class?

### Background

The base class in my case is `UndirectedGraph` (from QuickGraph library). Among other things there are two members in this class that I don't want to serialize:

```
public class UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge>
{
  public IEnumerable<TEdge> Edges { get; }
  public IEnumerable<TVertex> Vertices { get; }
}
```

So I derived from this class and make my own. I then redefined these two members with `new` and applied `IgnoreDataMember` on them. Like this:

```
public class OurGraph : UndirectedGraph
{
  [IgnoreDataMember]
  public new IEnumerable<XMLDoc> Vertices => base.Vertices;

  [IgnoreDataMember]
  public new IEnumerable<OurEdge> Edges => base.Edges;
}
```

Now I use `DataContractSerializer` to write an object of `OurGraph` to a file:

```
public static string SerializeDC(this object obj)
{
  XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
  Namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

  System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

  using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
  {
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, myXmlWriterSettings))
    {
      DSSerializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
      xmlWriter.Close();
    }

    writer.Close();
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately, those two members still find their way into the output. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

While doing further experimentation, it looks like `IgnoreDataMember` will not work unless you apply `DataContract` attribute on the containing class. Now applying `DataContract` attribute on a class requires its base class to also have `DataContract` (or `Serializable`) attribute applied on it, which in my case is a third-party class and I can't change that code.

Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Serializable attribute on class.
2. Use NonSerialized attribute on class property for which you don't want to serialize.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I hear that `NonSerialized` attribute has no effect on `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: Plus `NonSerialized` can only be applied on fields, not properties.